# Indentar llamada a función muy larga

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una llamada a una función que es muy larga y no sé cuál sería la forma correcta de indentarla ya que la lista de argumentos está al límite recomendado de caracteres por línea:

```
mask_star, leng_m_star_small, leng_m_star_big = tls.mask_chirp_star(n, p0, a, lb, times_ext, pv, increm, p_central)
```

Si lo indento como yo entiendo que debería hacerlo me queda así:

```
mask_star, leng_m_star_small, leng_m_star_big = tls.mask_chirp_star(n, p0,
                                                                    a, lb,
                                                                    times_ext,
                                                                    pv,
                                                                    increm,
                                                                    p_central)
```

E incluso de esta forma hay dos variables que superan el límite de caracteres.

Sé que los nombres de las variables son muy largos, pero me gustaría dejarlos como están.

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de indentarlo para ponerlo en más de una línea?

Comment: El limite de 79 caracteres por línea no deja de ser una recomendación, por lo que eventualmente podrías dejar todo en una sola línea que creo es lo mejor en este caso. Sino, podrías retornar los valores en una sola variable `ret` y luego "abrirlos"  en otra línea `mask_star, leng_m_star_small, leng_m_star_big = ret`. No te respondo directamente por que no sería más que una opinión.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho quería ceñirme a la recomendación de los 79 caracteres sin recurrir a artificios. En cualquier caso, tu propuesta de retornar los valores en una variable me parece interesante y no se me había ocurrido. Lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Es una opción, pero estoy más interesado en saber cual es la recomendación en estos casos. Quizá sea precisamente lo que comentas, pero no lo sé.

Comment: @JackNavaRow En realidad no busco una respuesta basada en opiniones si no más bien en algo del tipo [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: estas buscando el estandar de phyton para declarar y asignar metodos y variables?

Comment: No. Estoy preguntando el estándar (si es que lo hay) para indentar una línea de código como la que muestro.